# random vectors and matices

Tags: probability

I have a random vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{g}$ and a random matrix $Z$. the distributions of $Z$ and $\vec{g}$ are known. By having the relation $Z \cdot\vec{a}=\vec{g}$, how can I find the probability distribution of $\vec{a}$?

Comment: I don't know much about this I'm afraid, but a small observation: if $Z=0$ a.s. then $a$ can have any distribution at all; similarly, if $Z$ is singular with positive probability then the distribution of $a$ will not be uniquely determined. So there is not going to be a single answer in general.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have to repeat the question, saying that the two states that user108903 has mentioned are not  
acceptable.